Why the need to `decode_utf8` LDAP attribute values in an UTF-8 enviromment?
I wrote a Perl program (5.18.2 using NET::LDAP (perl-ldap-0.44-10.3.1.x86_64), both from SLES12 SP5) in an UTF-8 environment (LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8", Emacs displays "UUU") that reads an UTF-8 encoded file, inserts some attribute values read from an OpenLDAP server, and then writes the result into an UTF-8 encoded file.
It seems I had to use
use utf8;
use open IO => ':locale';
use open ':std' => ':locale';
use feature qw(unicode_strings);

in addition to binmode $fh, ":utf8"; before writing the output to $fh.
With these additions the string lengths inside Perl seem correct, and the output file, too.
However as I found out lately, attribute values from LDAP (the result of some $ldap->search()) that contain non-ASCII characters (like a German Umlaut) are not correct.
As they looked to me like "double-encoded", I added decoding them like this (to create a hash reference for the entry, keyed by DN):
$data{$entry->dn} = {map {
    $_ => [map { decode_utf8($_) } $entry->get_value($_)]
} $entry->attributes(NLK_NO_OPTIONS => 1)};

While working, this looks strange, and I wonder whether there is a more elegant solution (after all I don't really understand what's going on internally).
For testing I had created a user like this:
dn: uid=testuser,ou=people,dc=company,dc=org
cn: User Test
gidNumber: 54321
givenName: User
homeDirectory: /tmp/testuser
loginShell: /bin/bash
sn: Test
uid: testuser
uidNumber: 54321
objectClass: top
objectClass: posixAccount
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
displayName:: QsO2c2VyIFVtbGF1dCBpbSBOYW1lbg==

Without the fix the displayName would be displayed as "BÃ¶ser Umlaut im Namen", and after the fix it's displayed as "Böser Umlaut im Namen".

Please add a complete example . You don‘t even show the LDAP library used. Read for example https://metacpan.org/dist/perl-ldap/view/lib/Net/LDAP.pod#raw-=%3E-REGEX

Every utf8 string that   enters your program has to be decoded every utf8 string that  leaves your program  has to be encoded.  Either your library has a switch to decode incoming data, or you have to do it in your code.

So you're saying $ldap->search() is returning encoded text. And you think that's wrong. But you didn't say anything about $ldap???

Tip: binmode $fh, ":utf8"; should be binmode $fh, ":encoding(UTF-8)";. Except it's not needed at all because  of the use open.

Tip: If you do use open ':std' => ':locale';, you don't also need use open IO => ':locale';. It's already done by use open ':std' => ':locale';.

@clamp  Perl used is old 5.18.2, and the Net::LDAP library is perl-ldap-0.44-10.3.1.x86_64 fro SLES 12. Extracting a complete example would be a lot of work, and it would be quite lengthy, and when rewriting most code, it's questionable whether the effect could be reproduced.

@ikegami $ldap = Net::LDAP->new($host) (also TLS started and "bound" with some credentials). Is that precise enough?

@ikegami On "binmode": Reading "perldoc -f binmode", it says about layers: "The ":bytes", ":crlf", ":utf8", and any other directives of the form ":...", are called I/O layers.", so I guessed I used it correctly. It also explains "To mark FILEHANDLE as UTF-8, use ":utf8" or ":encoding(UTF-8)". ":utf8" just marks the data as UTF-8 without further checking, while ":encoding(UTF-8)" checks the data for actually being valid UTF-8.", so thanks for that hint.

$ldap = Net::LDAP->new($host) … did you read the doc link i gave you above?  https://metacpan.org/dist/perl-ldap/view/lib/Net/LDAP.pod#raw-=%3E-REGEX

If this option is not given, attribute values are treated as byte strings

:utf8 can result in corrupt scalars (and utf8 is not UTF-8). So I repeat: binmode $fh, ":utf8"; should be binmode $fh, ":encoding(UTF-8)";.

@clamp seems like you should post that as the answer

You have to think about all data boundaries. Sometime the library does it for you, sometimes it doesn't. If the library doesn't do it for you, you have to do it yourself.
Libraries might hide those details from you, but at some point something has to know something about the input. You are going to get octets. There's nothing magical about encodings, which are really just instructions about interpreting groups of eight bits.  When you are exchanging data, you eventually have to deal with the wire protocol.
Perl can use the environment as hints for how to treat the bits, but that doesn't mean those hints are correct. You might even have multiple input sources, each of which have different encodings.
In the world of JSON, which is always UTF-8, all of this seems really weird. That also makes the rest of the world seem really stupid for not being UTF-8 all the time. But, it hasn't been simple to get to this point either.
But, many of the things we use have been around much longer than UTF-8; I think LDAP and UTF-8 started roughly the same time. Some things that came later implemented their UTF-8 support ... oddly (consider How to make MySQL handle UTF-8 properly). Some things implemented their Unicode support before UTF-8 was a possibility, and they couldn't change on a dime.
I still run into some UTF-16 things, which is a whole other mess since there are different UTF-16s. Back in the days of my scientific career, I had to know details about the hardware so I knew how to treat the bytes on the tape. I think it's been a long time since anyone cared about big-endian or little-endian (or even "network" order). Those were often not "big" or "little"; perl's little endian unpack template letter is "V" for VAX.

Brian, it's probably all correct what you are saying, but I can't match all with my question: I'm giving  hints (as many that I thought to be necessary) to Perl, telling it's UTF-8 what is input, what is written in the source code, and what's going to be written to files. Just the result of Net::LDAP::search seems to input something different into Perl.

But it's not as many as necessary. LDAP doesn't care how you set up your session. It's going to return the data however it returns the data. The module you are using does not decode that for you (it could, but doesn't), so you have to do it yourself.

But isn't the result that LDAP returns UTF-8 anyway? Does it mean it's UTF-8, but Perl does not know (thus encoding it again)?

You'd have to look at your LDAP setup. Even then, something still has to decode it.

Net::LDAP is documented to return raw bytes unless you are configuring it otherwise. Perl can't tell whether a sequence of bytes are binary data or a string in utf-8 encoding.
Net::LDAP has the raw => regex configuration option as documented here
For example adding raw => qr/^jpeg/ to your constructor $ldap = Net::LDAP->new($host, raw => qr/^jpeg/) will ensure content of attributes starting with jpeg is treated as binary and content of attributes not matching this regex will be decoded from utf-8.

Actually I don't read the manual page that way: raw => REGEX explains: "Use REGEX to denote the names of attributes that are to be considered binary in search results." - In my interpretation that means that the default is (UTF-8) text. - Like a miracle the page continues (shouldn't it know the version it describes?): "If this option is not given or the version of Perl Net::LDAP is running on is too old strings are encoded the same as in earlier versions of perl-ldap."

The link I provided contains the sentence If this option is not given, attribute values are treated as byte strings  I can not see any ambiguity in this statement.

Also i do not see the sentence you quoted in your comment. Perhaps the docs have been clarified recently and your version is not the latest…

If the result just were "bytes" strings, then the result when UTF-8 encoded would be valid UTF-8, right? However it looked "double-encoded", so I don't think they were byte strings.

The socket receives a stream of bytes. These might represent a string encoded in UTF-8. If you do not decode them and (for testing purposes) print them without encoding them ( binmode($fh,':raw') would ensure that )  , they will appear unchanged in your output. However if you encode your output ( you should and binmode($fh,':encoding(UTF-8)') does that ) you have to decode the string from UTF-8 when reading it. Otherwise perl will treat the raw bytes as Latin1 or some such and encode them to UTF-8 which leads to garbage.
